# How to keep all elements of a list in one row while creating a dataframe from it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list `lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']` .
Now, if I create a dataframe from it like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['char'])
```

Then, it becomes like below:

```
    char
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

But, I want to keep all elements in a row. For example:

```
    char
0   ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I do this using Pandas? Any help?

Answer (score 6):

Use nested list:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame([[lst]], columns=['char'])
    
print (df)
        char
0  [a, b, c]
```

Comment: I tried with `list(lst)`, didn't work. But `[]` is working! LOL. Thank you anyway.